# How to struct Json format to return two arrays in Web API MVC

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object, asp.net-web-api

I want to go back to JSON format two separate arrays. For now, I'm returning one List and filling all the data there.

How can I create an object with two arrays and fill Station, Ime and Cell in one array and TA, RH, WS, SR, APRES with other array.

I have one class with 3 objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebAPI2.Models

{

public class Stations
{
    public string Station { get; set; }

    public string Ime { get; set; }

    public string Cell { get; set; }



  }

public class otherData
{
    public string DATS { get; set; }

    public string TA { get; set; }

    public string RH { get; set; }

    public string WS { get; set; }

    public string SR { get; set; }

    public string APRES { get; set; }
}

public class getAllValues
{
    public List<Stations> Stations { get; set; }

    public List<otherData> Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the ValuesController I create two foreach with two separate Lists, But I dont know how to return them.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using WebAPI2.Models;

namespace WebAPI2.Controllers
{

[RoutePrefix("API/Stations")]

public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    [Route("")]
    // GET api/values

    public IEnumerable<getAllValues> Get()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = WebApiConfig.conn();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
        }
        catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
        {
            string err = "Error: " + ex;
        }

        MySqlCommand executeStations = new MySqlCommand("select Stationsall.station,stationsall.Ime,Cell from stationsall join stations_cells using (Station);", conn);

        MySqlCommand executeData = new MySqlCommand("CALL Get_mod_cell_values_meteogram ('2018-01-27 00:00:00',42020,5);", conn);

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(executeStations);

        MySqlDataAdapter da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(executeData);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(dt);

        da1.Fill(dt1);

        List<Stations> Stations = new List<Stations>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            Stations getAllStations = new Stations
            {
                Station = dr["station"].ToString(),
                Ime = dr["Ime"].ToString(),
                Cell = dr["Cell"].ToString()
            };

            Stations.Add(getAllStations);              

            //returnedData(dr["station"].ToString(), dr["Ime"].ToString(), dr["Cell"].ToString());
        }

        List<otherData> otherData = new List<otherData>();

        foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt1.Rows)
        {
            otherData getAllData = new otherData
            {
                DATS = dr1["DATS"].ToString(),
                TA = dr1["TA"].ToString(),
                RH = dr1["RH"].ToString(),
                WS = dr1["WS"].ToString(),
                SR = dr1["SR"].ToString(),
                APRES = dr1["APRES"].ToString()
            };

            otherData.Add(getAllData);
        }

        return /*how to return otherData and Stations ?*/;


        }      
    }
}
```

Comment: you can probably have 2 extra classes with your first data in one class and second data in another and refer these two classes in your Station class

Comment: Can you explain me with example ? :) I really dont know how exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make separete view models for all data. 
You need 3 clases:
1st)

```
public class StationViewModel
{

    public string Station { get; set; }

    public string Ime { get; set; }

    public string Cell { get; set; }
}
```

2nd

```
public class DataViewModel
{
    public string DATS { get; set; }

    public string TA { get; set; }

    public string RH { get; set; }

    public string WS { get; set; }

    public string SR { get; set; }

    public string APRES { get; set; }
}
```

3rd

```
public class TableViewModel
{
     public List<StationViewModel> Stations { get; set; }

     public List<DataViewModel> Data { get; set; }
}
```

And than make mapping from Yours object to new view models.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
var getAllValuesList = new List<getAllValues>()
{
    new getAllValues()
    {
        Stations = Stations,
        Data  = otherData 
    }
};
return getAllValuesList;
```

Comment: I update my question with your code but I want a little bit more to struct to two arrays :)

Comment: @ВалерияБлаговест
do not inherit Stations from other data, if You want to have separate tables. When You inherit you just add properties from otherData to station

Comment: Ok, but how to return this two lists ?

Comment: What You want to achieve?
To separate lists with relations between each other?

Comment: and how data structure in db looks like? What are primary keys for this data?

Comment: There are 2 separate querries .. I want to display One querry in one list.. and second querry in second list.. for now I have two Lists Stations and Data.. I will update the code with foreaches for one lists and foreach for second lists but I dont know how to return this two lists..

Comment: Can You please accept answer if it was helpfull? :)